# Converting escaped characters to UTF-8 in bash

Tags: utf-8, text-rendering

I have a large text file containing sequences such as

\u02BBUtthay\u0101n h\u01E3ng Ch\u0101t Khao Yai

However, they render exactly as above. How do I convert this so people just see UTF-8? I would prefer to process the files at the command line if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the printf command.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man3/printf.3.html

you can wrap it in $() to use as a variable if needed, too.

For example,

```
echo $(printf '\u02BBUtthay\u0101n h\u01E3ng Ch\u0101t Khao Yai')
```

this outputs: ʻUtthayān hǣng Chāt Khao Yai

Hope that helps.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with a variable as an argument, only with a literal. This is because the backslash got lost when I read the variable from file. Solved with "read -r".